# Stop/Restart node.js server

Tags: node.js, javascript

В данный момкент тушу cmd и вызываю запуск сервера вновь.Жутко неудобно.
Есть команда которая тушить сервер и запускает рестарт с консоля?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А Ctrl+C, стрелка вверх и Enter никак?

Comment: Способ золото....Благодарен...А как остановить?

Comment: Дык, Ctrl-C как раз останавливает
Запускаешь-то ты его как-то так: node app.js в консоли cmd

Comment: Есть отличные удобные модули, Ctrl+С это типа, Ctrl+Alt+Del для выключения компьютера. Используйте nodemon, forever это реально удобно.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно есть - [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) и pm2. [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) - вообще зверь, для production самое то. forever и [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) для повседневной работы. Это уже классика.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотреть процессы (напр, вебсервер на Node, который занимает нужный порт):
**ps -ef** 
если нужно конкретно какой-то процесс найти(напр, node), то:
**ps -ef | grep node** 
потом убить нужный по PID (например, 133):
**kill -9 133**